# How to increase MongoDB performance

Tags: mongodb, cakephp

I am developing an application in MongoDB, CakePHP. I have **145,000** record in my database. When I query for records using following command then it takes **12seconds**. Which is very bad for my application.

```
$params= array('aggregate'=>array(
     array('$project'=>array('as'=>1,'pid'=>1,'st'=>1)),
     array('$unwind'=>'$as'),                   
     array('$match' => array('pd'=>array('$gt'=>$f,'$lt'=>$t),'pid'=>$project_id)),
     array('$group'=>array('_id'=>'$as')), 
     array('$sort'=>array('_id'=>1)),
     array('$limit'=>10)
     )
);
$results = $this->Detail->find('all',array('conditions'=>$params));
```

Can anyone help me in reducing time for query.

I have indexes on **as** & **pid**. My system RAM is 1.5GB.

I got following data as result

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [Detail] => Array
            (
                [_id] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => "superfone" Llc,moscow,ru
                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Detail] => Array
            (
                [_id] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => "superphone" Llc,moscow,ru
                    )

            )

    )
```

Comment: From MongoDb console: `db.stats()` from the correct database. Results? It looks like your unwinding an array in all 145k documents...that's not optimal.

Comment: Also, try running the aggregation from the console. How long does it take? You could do it iteratively to find the relative cost for each pipeline step.

Comment: Put the `$match` before the `$project`, if possible.  Also, why are you including the `st` field in the `$project` and then not using it?  Why are you referencing the `pd` field in the `$match` when that field isn't included in your `$project`?

Comment: I second @WiredPrairie's suggestion that you should run the aggregation query in the `mongo` shell. That will help separate any overhead of `CakePHP` from the underlying query, and you can also test adding a pipeline step at a time to understand which steps are slow. Assuming your `$match` step is to filter matching documents in an array, you should also add a similar `$match` at the start of your pipeline so you're only working with matching documents rather than all documents in that collection.

Comment: The problem is solved as it takes only 1s on live server with 8GB of RAM. But I will surely try the some optimizations given by @WiredPrairie

Answer (score 0):

Before performing the find, make sure to set the recursive level to the level you need, then report back on your performance.

```
$this->Detail->recursive = -1; // no joins
results = $this->Detail->find('all',array('conditions'=>$params));
```

or

```
$this->Detail->recursive = 0; // data + domain
results = $this->Detail->find('all',array('conditions'=>$params));
```

Not sure what level of recursive you need, so give them a test, but default is 1 and it can be a costly exercise.

**ref**
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive

The reference also says to make -1 your default, and raise the recursive levels as you need them, this can be done by adding the following to AppModel

```
public $recursive = -1;
```

Comment: I am editing question with data structure. But I am sure that there is no recursion occuring. Only required data of Details tables is coming.

Comment: Please see the updated question with retreived data.

Comment: You sure? did you give it a shot? There's a big difference between default of 1 which returns all hasMany items. I have a feeling this is the problem, array('$match' => array('pd'=>array('$gt'=>$f,'$lt'=>$t),'pid'=>$project_id)) but can't put my finger on it...

Comment: There is no hasMany and other relationships in my Model. And pd is priority date & $f & $t are years.

Comment: Yes, but when the sql is performing the joins maybe it's working with to much data, setting recursive to -1 will ensure it isn't loading it up, can you just try it to rule it out?

Comment: No difference by applying recursive= -1 or 0

Comment: I been trying my hardest to find you an answer but I can't find anything, apparently aggregations are troublesome in cakephp with mongodb -.-

Comment: Try running a script of the Aggregation on the MongoDB to rule out if it's your MongoDB Query Or CakePHP. If It's MongoDB we will know how to better tackle it.... Do that and update your question.

Comment: No probs thanks for this. Hope person like Jon Skeet will come :P

Comment: Also, try making a query dump to see what the query looks like, does <?php echo $this->element('sql_dump');?> work if you put it at the end of the layout to show you the query? Are you using this plugin ? https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/ Sorry my MongoDB is very limited....

Comment: An aggregation is unlikely to map back to the `Detail` class layout, so I don't understand what recursion would have to do with this?

Comment: Thanks. was just answering where I would start. I still haven't found a solution though, should i retract my answer, lol