# Aggregation in find query is not working while using aggregate method on collection do

Tags: mongodb, cakephp, php-mongodb

#### Works and returns me one record

```
db.gfk_products.aggregate([
    {$match : {product_id : '50910288'}},
    {$project : {
        features: "$features.key"
    }}
])
```

#### Does not return anything

```
db.gfk_products.find({

    aggregate : [
        {$match : {product_id : '50910288'}},
        {$project : {
            features: "$features.key"
        }}
    ]
})
```

Don't know why! Second query is generated by mongodb adapter for cakephp.

### EDIT

#### Respective Cakephp Code

```
$cond['conditions'] = array(
    'aggregate' => array(
        array(
            '$match' => array(
                'product_id' => $itemID
            ),
        ),
        array(
            '$project' => array(
                'features' => '$features.key'
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
$result = $this->Product->find('all',$cond);
```

Comment: I don't think you can do an aggregate from inside a find. Can you point me the document in MongoDB docs where you saw such kind of query?

Comment: How are you actually invoking this in CakePHP? There were actually some notes on this [here](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/pull/74). Perhaps you can add the code you are using to your question if that is unclear.

Comment: @NeilLunn Added respective cakephp code. I have gone through the link you shared following the same structure.

Comment: As per the link I gave in the previous comment does this still fail if you just reduce to `$cond = array( 'aggregate' ` etc?

Comment: yes it don't. as then I'll have to change the find call to $this->find->('all', array('conditions' => $cond)) which is exactly same.. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897382/how-to-increase-mongodb-performance

Comment: That is not what I said. Remove the 'conditions' key and have "aggregate" as the top level key. Effectively, `$this->find('all', array('aggregate' => $pipeline))` See the code where this was [commited](https://github.com/codingthoughts/cakephp-mongodb/commit/2a3433b53fe9a6fc576f88013934987b4480c209)

Comment: NO that don't work either.. I am not sure where the problem is.. I even can't get it working directly on mongo client.. Php afcourse will come later..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ankit,

There is no facility in MongoDB to execute aggregate pipeline via the find query. You can find more details about the method used specifically for aggregate in MongoDB/PHP driver - http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php .

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. But somehow that cakephp driver was generating it wrong way. Thanks.